# How to change date and fast time

Tags: java, calendar

I need to change the time of a date to 23.59. 
I can do it but the fast time remain the same so the date is actually not changed.

*start is my starting date exemple 6th december 2017 at 9.31am

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(start);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    start = calendar.getTime();
```

I have start date at 6th december 2017 at 23.59am but the fast time is still the same.

How can I do?

Comment: Why do you need changing fast time?

Comment: What is the "fast time"?

Comment: Do you mean `Date.fastTime`, i.e. the value in `start` after reassigning it with `calendar.getTime()`?

Comment: How do you check the date hasn't actually changed? Can you provide a [mcve]? I have a feeling that you're passing `start` as a method parameter and expect the date to be changed in the caller. If that's the case then note that java is call-by-value, i.e. reassigning `start` won't change the date instance in the caller of that method.

Comment: Yes it's Date.fastTime.    Basically whatever I do it remains the same

Comment: Aren’t you concerned with an implementation detail that you shouldn’t worry about?

Comment: Why are you using `Date` and `Calendar`? Both classes are long outdated, and today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API (also known as JSR-310)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You say you need to change to 23:59, but your code seems to change to 0:00:00?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my computer I get `Thu Dec 14 00:00:00 CET 2017`. The `Date` is changed.

Comment: In one run `start.fastTime` changed from 1513251059783 to 1513206000783. It too changed. I seriously don’t think you’ve got the problem you think you have.

Comment: Thanks Ole VV. start was declared as a new Date(). I'll try with Calendar()

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you stop using the `Calendar` class and use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API for your task:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(
            2017, 12, 6, 9, 31, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Canada/Newfoundland"));

    // to change time to 0:00:00
    dateTime = dateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println("Changed to 0:00:       " + dateTime);
    // to change to end of day
    dateTime = dateTime.with(LocalTime.MAX);
    System.out.println("Changed to end of day: " + dateTime);
    // if you need it without seconds
    dateTime = dateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
    System.out.println("Changed to 23:59:      " + dateTime);
```

This prints

```
Changed to 0:00:       2017-12-06T00:00-03:30[Canada/Newfoundland]
Changed to end of day: 2017-12-06T23:59:59.999999999-03:30[Canada/Newfoundland]
Changed to 23:59:      2017-12-06T23:59-03:30[Canada/Newfoundland]
```

The classes `Date` and `Calendar` are long outmoded. `java.time` is so much nicer to work with (it is also known as JSR-310).

I recommend you specify explicitly which time zone you want your time in. So fill in yours unless it happens to be Canada/Newfoundland. To use your JVM’s time zone setting use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but beware that this setting may be changed by other parts of your program or other programs running in the same JVM.

In case `start` is a `Date` you got from a legacy API that you do not want to change just now, start by converting it to `java.time.Instant` and do the remainder of your operations from there:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = start.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Canada/Newfoundland"));
```

The rest is the same as above. If the opposite was the case, you need to pass a `Date` to a legacy API at the end, the opposite conversion is:

```
    start = Date.from(dateTime.toInstant());
```

### What went wrong in your code?

There’s is nothing wrong with your code. At least on my computer it behaves as expected. I would be very surprised if it didn’t on yours. A bit of speculation: You may have noticed that the first and the last digits of the value of `start.fastTime` were the same, and this could have fooled you into thinking the value had not changed. If this was the problem, it may help you to add this line:

```
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

This will make sure that `fastTime` ends in at least five zeroes, for example `1513206000000`, and it will be more conspicuous that it has changed. Fortunately, the modern API offers the `truncatedTo` method, an easy way to obtain zeroes on the last places of your milliseconds value.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)